# Cannot bind PersistentVolumeClaim to PersistentVolume in namespace

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to install jenkins on my kubernetes cluster under `jenkins` namespace. When I deploy my pv and pvc, the pv remains available and does not bind to my pvc.

Here is my yamls:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  labels:
    type: jenkins
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

Below is my Storageclass for manual. Standard class has not been changed, should be the same as the default standard on kubernetes.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"manual"},"provisioner":"kubernetes.io/no-provisioner","volumeBindingMode":"WaitForFirstConsumer"}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-06-14T14:41:39Z"
  name: manual
  resourceVersion: "3643100822"
  uid: 8254d900-58e5-49e1-a07e-1830096aac87
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Comment: I see the `storageClassName`s are different for both.. could that be the reason?

Comment: Unfortunatley not. Just tried with both as manual, then both as standard.

Comment: could you also add your spec for the storage classes? could it be that they provision storage dynamically meaning creating PVC internally creates a PV so the manual created one stays unbound? you could run `kubectl get pv` to see if any additional PV is created when creating the PVC.

Comment: Spec added, i added this manual spec when i was trying to fix my issue

Comment: I think the problem is the `volumeBindingMode` being set as `WaitForFirstConsumer` which means the PV will remain unbound until there is a pod to consume it. You can change it `Immediate` to bind it immediately without requiring a pod. The `WaitForFirstConsumer` helps in saving resources in case of dynamic provisioning. you can read the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#volume-binding-mode) for detail. Let me know if this solves the issue.

Comment: Yes this has solved the issue! Thank you Krishna :)

Comment: I was thinking the issue was about namespaces because `PVC` is a namespaced object and for me it worked with `volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer` without any issues.

Comment: @moonkotte, you must also be creating a `Pod` that refers that PVC which @Volken is not doing hence is seeing the issue and you don't.

Comment: Thank you for response @KrishnaChaurasia. Deleted everything and only created `pv` and `pvc` and they "found" each other. Anyway this is resolved, was curious about the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the storage class spec, I think the problem is the `volumeBindingMode` being set as `WaitForFirstConsumer` which means the PV will remain unbound until there is a Pod to consume it.

You can change it `Immediate` to allow the PV to be bound immediately without requiring to create a Pod.

You can read about the different volume binding modes in detail in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#volume-binding-mode).